# JS Won't Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have this code that I have made and have been trying to fix it for days. I am trying to make it redirect to whatever the $link variable is set to. All it does is just give me a blank page. Any answers?

```
<?php 
$l = $_GET['l'];
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'link');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE new_url='$l'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $link = $row['website'];
    $string = $row['new_url'];
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
         'window.location = $link;',
         '</script>';
} else {
    @include('./error.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: That mess is not executed on the client-side. Please show the rendered code instead.

Comment: Just a blank page.

Comment: Why do you want to use Javascript to redirect when you can do it with PHP?

Comment: @Archer That's how I learned to redirect.

Comment: @Teemu Data from the database.

Comment: It's overkill.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: user double quotes behalf of single quote like `"window.location = $link;",`
Better to use `header("location:$link");`

Comment: @SHAZ Thanks you.

Comment: You haven't included the error(s) you're getting or anything else that might help us debug this problem.

Comment: @ssube In the console there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd done ANY kind of debugging, like viewing the source of the page you're generating, or even checking your brower's debug console, you'd be TOLD about your syntax errors. You're generating this:

```
window.location = http://google.com;
```

Does that look like valid Javascript to you?

Never **EVER** directly dump text from PHP into a Javascript code block for this exact reason. PHP may just be outputting a URL, but it's going into a JS code block, so the JS code you're generating has to be VALID code. Always use `json_encode()`:

```
$link = json_encode($row['new_url']);
echo "window.location = $link;"
```

which produces:

```
window.location = 'http://google.com';
```

Note the `'` quotes...

Comment: I did what you said and it still doesn't work.